# Toggle on click (true or false)

Tags: jquery, boolean, toggle

I would like to toggle my variable `ovDeskVisible` with true of false on each click. Can I have some help please ?

```
function toggle_menu_desktop() {
    var ovDeskVisible = false;

    $('.toggle-menu').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        ovDeskVisible = true ? false : true;
    });

    if (ovDeskVisible == true) {
        $('.icon-menu').addClass('is-opened');
        $('html').addClass('stop-scrolling');
        $('.circle').addClass('Opacity, open');
    }
    if (ovDeskVisible == false) {
        $('.icon-menu').addClass('is-closed');
        $('html').removeClass('stop-scrolling');
        $('.circle').removeClass('Opacity, open');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Move `ovDeskVisible` out of `toggle_menu_desktop` function and use `ovDeskVisible = ! ovDeskVisible` to toggle.

```
var ovDeskVisible = false;

function toggle_menu_desktop() {

    $('.toggle-menu').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        ovDeskVisible = !ovDeskVisible;
    });

    ...
}
```